# How should the maximum mean percent change from baseline be calculated?

Tags: statistics

A colleague and I are debating how to calculate the **maximum mean percent change from baseline (PCFB)** for a set of data.

**I believe the correct way is as follows:**

1. Identify the baseline value for each individual
2. Calculate the PCFB at each timepoint for that individual
3. Calculate the mean PCFB for all individuals in each group at all times
4. Identify the maximum value

**My colleague argues one should:**

1. Calculate the mean values between all individuals at all timepoints in each group
2. Use the group baseline to calculate the PCFB at each time
3. Calculate the mean PCFB for each group at all times
4. Identify the maximum value

**Which method is more correct and can you direct me to a source that clearly states the correct procedure?**

I know it may be hard to find a source for this exact case, but I'd appreciate something that generally indicates whether individual change should be calculated before the means, or if the mean values should be calculated first.

Happy to provide sample data if that helps, just not sure what format to use.